# DateTime.now subtraction with value from database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

I need to be able to get the difference from the current date with the date from my database. If the difference is 30, I need to display a expiry date message. My code block looks as such:

```
var expiryDate = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(user[3]);
```

The thing is, this returns some weird numbers which I can't seem to manage. How would I go about getting just the number of days and then check if it is 30?

Thanks for having a look guys!

Comment: some information about the content of user[3] would be helpful (or what kind of Database you use, what the columntype is, etc). do you get an error? maybe you just want expiryDate.TotalDays for thedifference in days

Comment: Sometimes it's so hard to read MSDN to figure out the answer

Comment: Can you please post DateTime.Parse(user[3]) returns in which format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(user[3]);

TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;

int days = ts.Days;

if (days == 30){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(user[3])).TotalDays //this will give you the days.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timespan = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(user[3]);
var days = timespan.Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.TimeSpan diffResult = dt1  - dt2;

if(diffResult < 0)
{
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract two DateTime instances you get a [`Timespan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Validate your value against the [`TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) property of this timespan

```
var expiryDate = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(user[3]);
expiryDate.TotalDays > 30 // check in this fashion
```